# How use generalized suffix tree to match prefix string?

Tags: regular-expressions, strings, suffix-trees, string-matching

I know that generalized suffix tree can match substring for a given pattern.
But I have need a data structure which is able to

1. match prefix of many strings.
2. match sub string of of many strings.

For example:
The strings I have:

`abc, abcd, bcxabc,`

If the pattern is `abc`, I should match all three strings.

If the pattern is `^abc`, I should only match `abc, abcd`. The `^` represent the start of a string.

I know I can build another TRIE. But it will cost almost the same space.

If there any way to achieve this in generalized suffix tree?

Comment: Hint: Introduce a new alphabet symbol which represents the start of a string (the caret symbol in your example).

Comment: You mean when I build the suffix tree? Yeah, that's also a trick.